# JavaScript timestamp to check against MySQL

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, timestamp

This is probably very trivial but I can't for the life of me find any good documentation. I have an AJAX event setup where I need to send a timestamp from the client side to the server. The server script (PHP) will check the timestamp that it has been passed, against a `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in a mysql table and act upon the results.

My problem is that I need to create a timestamp in JavaScript on the client page that will be comparable to the mysql timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex almost had it

The only thing that is wrong is that JS timestamps are in milliseconds and UNIX timestamps are in seconds. Therefore you need to divide the JS timestamp by 1000.

```
var unixNow = Math.round( (new Date().getTime()) / 1000);
```

Comment: Damn, did I mistake multiplication with division? That's what I get for working on a public holiday...

Answer (score 1):

How about just sending seconds from Epoch from JavaScript...

```
var secondsFromEpoch = ~~(+new Date / 1000);
```

..and then change your query to...

```
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`datetime`) == :secondsFromEpoch_passed_from_JavaScript
```

?

Comment: Some explanation for alex's tricky JS here. `+ new Date` is the same as `new Date().getTime()` the `+` converts the date to a number. The `~~` is another way to implement `Math.round()`, I've heard it's even faster

Comment: @JuanMendes Thanks for the explanation. However, `+` calls the `Date`'s `valueOf()` which returns a `Number`. Secondly, `~~`, or double invert bits, is functionally the same as `Math.floor()`.

Comment: @alex: First: You said the same thing I said??? The `+` before a date converts it to a number of milliseconds, you just added that it's because it calls `valueOf()`. Secondly `~~` is not the same as `Math.floor` either, so we were both wrong. `Math.floor(-8.3) == -9` and `~~(-8.3) == -8`. Therefore, it's the same as `Math.floor` for positive numbers and `Math.ceil` for negative numbers. So I don't think it's a very good idea, since you'd have different behavior for dates before and after 1970.

Comment: @JuanMendes I had not noticed the negative number problem before, I'll have to be mindful of that in the future. Also, is exploiting the fact the date works with a negative `Number` a good way to work with pre 1970 dates? That's a question in itself I guess...

Comment: Never had a problem with negative dates. From https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Description *The JavaScript date is measured in milliseconds since midnight 01 January, 1970 UTC. A day holds 86,400,000 milliseconds. The JavaScript Date object range is -100,000,000 days to 100,000,000 days relative to 01 January, 1970 UTC*